# Generate subset of length upto k

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I have written down code that is able to generate subsets of an `exact length 'k' from an input of length>'k'`

I am unable to actually come up with code that generates all subset up-to length 'k'

```
public static void pset(List<Integer> original, List<Integer> lst, int k, int idx) {
    if(lst.size() == k) {
        System.out.println(lst);
        return;
    }

    if(idx == original.size()) {
        return;
    }

    lst.add(original.get(idx));
    pset(original,lst,k,idx+1);
    lst.remove(lst.size()-1);
    pset(original,lst,k,idx+1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    var original = List.of(1,2,3,4);
    pset(original, new ArrayList<>(),2,0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void pset(List<Integer> original, List<Integer> lst, int k, int idx) {
        if(idx ==  original.size() || lst.size() == k) {
            if (lst.size() <= k)
                System.out.println(lst);
            return;
        }


        lst.add(original.get(idx));
        pset(original,lst,k,idx+1);
        lst.remove(lst.size()-1);
        pset(original,lst,k,idx+1);
}
```

When `idx == original.size()` that means you reached the end of the list by taking a subset of them, check if the taken subset length is at most `k`.

Comment: I would suggest changing the initial statement from `if(idx ==  original.size())` to `if(idx ==  original.size() || lst.size() == k)` so that it doesn't needlessly recurse.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy can you share the prior suggestion as well please?